# Regular expression a little too greedy

Tags: php, regex, regex-greedy

I am trying to capture a small subset of a document with this RegEx:

```
preg_match('/href="(.+?)".+?>Keyword/s', $a, $b);
```

However, instead of just grabbing the `href=` immediately before the `Keyword`, it starts at the first `href=` in the document and goes *alllllll* the way down to the `Keyword`.

How can I make it so it backtracks and only keeps the `href=` immediately before `Keyword`?

Comment: If the whole thing is on 1 line, you can remove `s` flag

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in the input, the text surrounded by the anchor tag is on the same line as the tag, you can remove the `s` flag.

Otherwise, you need a more specific regex:

```
'/href="[^"]*"[^<>]*>Keyword/'
```

This assumes that the link inside `href` does not contain `"`. The `[^<>]` prevents other tags from being part of the match.

Comment: Not exactly sure why this works but it seemed to have fixed the greediness issue. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanPeschel: Your regex can spans multiple tags, because `<>` is never disallowed, and the regex inside the href attribute is too permissive. I only make sure the `<>` is disallowed, and the href attribute is closed properly.

Comment: You should be able to omit the `[^<>]*` as the quotation already disables matching other tags. This only works though if your document looks like this `href="mylink">myKeyword`. If not keep nhahtdh's solution.

Comment: @LucasHoepner: No, the quotation doesn't prevent matching other tags - the `(.+?)` will just match anything. And the regex can match `href="link" onclick="...">Keyword`

Comment: "Omit" - not "replace with `(.+?)`" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no `"` can be inside the `href` attribute, you could start tuning your regex with this:

```
preg_match('/href="([^"]+?)".+?>Keyword/s', $a, $b);
```